# WordPress admin_ajax error

Tags: wordpress, admin-ajax

I'm getting a very weird issue triggering admin Ajax. I added the bellow functions to my `functions.php` file

```
add_action('wp_ajax_submit_quiz', 'quiz_submit');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_quiz', 'quiz_submit');
```

matter is, only `add_action('wp_ajax_submit_quiz', 'quiz_submit')` this one is executing for logged in user but `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_quiz', 'quiz_submit');` this one is not executing on live server. Locally they both work fine.

Any guideline or help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: I think the error may be in the callback (or anything else) and not in the code above.

Comment: Which error you get?

Comment: I get empty response. When using wp_ajax_nopriv admin-ajax not working. It's working only for authenticated users.